# Can I append the data to the div using jTemplate

Tags: jquery, httphandler, jtemplates, jtemplate

Hi i am using the jTemplates for rendering the data through html controls,
By using

```
$('div#table-jtemplates').setTemplate(x);    
$('div#table-jtemplates').processTemplate(data);
```

Can i append the data to the specific div.by above i am able to replace the whole data.
can any one help me out of this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Ive not worked on jTemplates ,but by the look of it if you want to append data to specific div then take the html inside that div in a seperate template and then process it.
like you have already done:

```
$('new div').setTemplate("new template created with divs html");    
$('new div').processTemplate(data);
```

Comment: HI @farhan,Thanks for your reply.what is the new means here

Comment: 'new div' is just the div in which you want to append the data, like   $("#divId").setTemplate(template); $("#divId").processTemplate(data);

Answer (score 0):

jtemplates works by processing whats in the template against the data you are sending it

if you want to APPEND more data, you'd need to do a loop in the template itself

e.g.

```
<div id='mydiv'>
    {#foreach $T.years as year}
        <td class="aright bt italic cyear_{$T.year}" id="total_super_{$T.year}">0</td>
    {#/for}
</div>
```

Then you'd:

```
$('new div').setTemplate("mydiv");    
$('new div').processTemplate({years: [1,2,3,4]});
```

As there are 4 years it would create 4 of these elements